# Authentication - Xamarin.Forms, Azure Mobile Apps

Tags: android, authentication, xamarin.forms, uwp, azure-mobile-services

I've got a Xamarin.Forms app (iOS, Android, UWP) connected to Azure Mobile Apps' authentication service. From what I read, it seemed pretty straightforward to implement. I'm testing in a UWP project, and Android, both get the same result.

When logging in, I get this lovely "can't connect to the service you need right now." I don't see anything wrong in my code. What might be going on here?

**Windows UWP:**

```
public async Task<bool> Authenticate()
{
    string message = string.Empty;
    var success = false;

    try
    {
        // Sign in with Facebook login using a server-managed flow.
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = await TaskService.DefaultService.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
            if (user != null)
            {
                success = true;
                message = string.Format("You are now signed-in as {0}.", user.UserId);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        message = string.Format("Authentication Failed: {0}", ex.Message);
    }

    // Display the success or failure message.
    await new MessageDialog(message, "Sign-in result").ShowAsync();

    return success;
}
```

**Android:**

```
public async Task<bool> Authenticate()
{
    var success = false;
    var message = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        // Sign in with Facebook login using a server-managed flow.
        user = await TaskService.DefaultService.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(this,
            MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
        if (user != null)
        {
            message = string.Format("you are now signed-in as {0}.",
                user.UserId);
            success = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        message = ex.Message;
    }

    // Display the success or failure message.
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.SetMessage(message);
    builder.SetTitle("Sign-in result");
    builder.Create().Show();

    return success;
}
```

**Can't connect to service error:**
[image: Can't connect to service error in Windows UWP]

**The settings on Facebook for the app:**
[image: Facebook App Settings]

Visited:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-facebook-authentication/
- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/azure/

**EDIT:**
I've tried moving the client code to App.cs:

```
private static MobileServiceClient _Client;
public static MobileServiceClient Client
{
    get
    {
        if(_Client == null) _Client = new MobileServiceClient(AppConstants.AzureMobileServiceURL);
        return _Client;
    }
    set { _Client = value; }
}
```

And the new call in MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
uesr = await Slated.App.Client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
```

Same result!

Another note: My Azure Mobile Services URL **does** include https://

**EDIT 2:**
Code below for logging on backend, looks to be an issue when redirecting to /login/facebook, the rest of the authentication appears to proceed OK. FYI - replaced the sensitive data with ____

```
2016-07-29T18:38:43  PID[6684] Verbose     Received request: GET https://________.azurewebsites.net/login/facebook
2016-07-29T18:38:43  PID[6684] Information Redirecting: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=_____________&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F________.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=public_profile&state=_____________________________&display=popup
2016-07-29T18:38:50  PID[6684] Verbose     Received request: GET https://________.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook/callback?code=____________________
2016-07-29T18:38:50  PID[6684] Verbose     Calling into external HTTP endpoint GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token.
2016-07-29T18:38:51  PID[6684] Verbose     Calling into external HTTP endpoint GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token.
2016-07-29T18:38:51  PID[6684] Verbose     Calling into external HTTP endpoint GET https://graph.facebook.com/me.
2016-07-29T18:38:51  PID[6684] Information Login completed for 'Thomas Gardner'. Provider: 'facebook'.
2016-07-29T18:38:51  PID[6684] Verbose     Writing 'AppServiceAuthSession' cookie for site '________.azurewebsites.net'. Length: 512.
2016-07-29T18:38:51  PID[6684] Information Redirecting: https://________.azurewebsites.net/login/facebook
2016-07-29T18:38:51  PID[6684] Verbose     Received request: GET https://________.azurewebsites.net/login/facebook
2016-07-29T18:38:51  PID[6684] Verbose     Found 'AppServiceAuthSession' cookie for site '________.azurewebsites.net'. Length: 512.
2016-07-29T18:38:51  PID[6684] Verbose     Authenticated Thomas Gardner successfully using 'Session Cookie' authentication.
2016-07-29T18:38:52  PID[6684] Verbose     Received request: GET https://________.azurewebsites.net/login/facebook
2016-07-29T18:38:52  PID[6684] Verbose     Found 'AppServiceAuthSession' cookie for site '________.azurewebsites.net'. Length: 512.
2016-07-29T18:38:52  PID[6684] Verbose     Authenticated __________ successfully using 'Session Cookie' authentication.
2016-07-29T18:38:52  PID[6684] Information Request, Method=GET, Url=https://________.azurewebsites.net/login/facebook, Message='https://________.azurewebsites.net/login/facebook'
2016-07-29T18:38:52  PID[6684] Information Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2016-07-29T18:38:52  PID[6684] Information Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
2016-07-29T18:38:52  PID[6684] Information Response, Status=404 (NotFound), Method=GET, Url=https://________.azurewebsites.net/login/facebook, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
```

**Backend Code:** It is copied from MSFT's template code. Not much has been done to the startup.
**Startup.Mobile.App.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        //For more information on Web API tracing, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=620686 
        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();

        new MobileAppConfiguration()
            .UseDefaultConfiguration()
            .ApplyTo(config);

        // Use Entity Framework Code First to create database tables based on your DbContext
        Database.SetInitializer(new SlatedInitializer());

        // To prevent Entity Framework from modifying your database schema, use a null database initializer
        // Database.SetInitializer<SlatedContext>(null);

        MobileAppSettingsDictionary settings = config.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.HostName))
        {
            // This middleware is intended to be used locally for debugging. By default, HostName will
            // only have a value when running in an App Service application.
            app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
            {
                SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
                ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"] },
                ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"] },
                TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
            });
        }
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}

public class SlatedInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SlatedContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(SlatedContext context)
    {
        /*List<Tasks> todoItems = new List<Tasks>
        {
            new Tasks { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "First item", Complete = false },
            new Tasks { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "Second item", Complete = false },
        };

        foreach (Tasks todoItem in todoItems)
        {
            context.Set<Tasks>().Add(todoItem);
        }*/

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you turn on Diagnostic Logs on the backend and review the logs to see if there are any errors.  Also, can you provide details of how the Authentication / Authorization section is configured?

Comment: Just added to the question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you include the versions of the client and server packages you're using?

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server: 1.1.0.0 // Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication: 1.1.0.0 // Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile: 1.3.0.0

Comment: I see the problem, you are mixing up the client and server packages. you need to use the client nuget package Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client, version 2 or above. To learn more, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-client-and-server-versioning.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the specifics of the client and server libraries. You didn't use any of the custom API or tables endpoints, it looks like, otherwise you would have gotten an exception immediately saying there was a version mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the URIs that are being used, it looks like you are mixing packages between Mobile Services and Mobile Apps. The two are **not** compatible.

To learn more, see [Client and server versioning in Mobile Apps and Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-client-and-server-versioning).

On the server, you should be using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.*. Make sure you have no packages in the form WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.

On the client, you must use the package [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client).

Comment: Done, I've updated it to include the conditional as it originally did, but I'm still getting the error and the diagnostic logs on the backend are the same.

Comment: @Thomas Can you update your post with the updated code, so it's easier to troubleshoot the steps you've already taken?

Comment: Done. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Perfect. This solved the problem, and I'm getting a successful sign in. Thank you for noticing that - the versions were indeed mismatched. After uninstalling the old packages, I reinstalled from NuGet and re-deployed. Good to go! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
user = await App.MobileService .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
```

try this line of code.This should work and for the user id 
you can simply do it like that :

```
var userId = user.Id;
```

Comment: Assuming you meant to change if (user != null) to if (user.UserId != null), then that doesn't help. Same result.

Comment: Nope,
I mean to replace that line :
user = await TaskService.DefaultService.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
      
with that line :

user = await App.MobileService .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);

Comment: and make sure that your mobile services url in the app.xaml.cs 
starts with https. It's required.

Comment: Updated question to reflect the changes, but ultimately it did not help consuming from App.cs instead of my Service.

Answer (score 0):

Well here how I do it : in the app.xaml.cs

```
 public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient("https://yourmobileservices.azurewebsites.net");
```

then in your code behind:

```
user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
```

and it works like a charm for me,And make sure that in azure portal in the 
Authentication tab that under advanced settings that Token store is on.

Comment: Have done this, too. It's what all the guides promise. Is it an issue with my Facebook auth settings? The redirect URL is causing the server to respond with 404 (.../login/facebook)

Comment: @Thomas see this UWP [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Facebook-authentification-bceea645) I hope it will help you.